# Manually break biblatex entry like date or number

Tags: biblatex, numbering, line-breaking, biber, isodate

I am running Biblatex with Biber and TexnicCenter with Miktex. How do I manually break the date or put it on the next line if it is at the end of an entry (ISO 8601, has to be broken or on a new line)? Same goes for the number for patents? In this MWE the patent number does not break, but in my main document the main issue is with the date, e. g. 2014-06-16. Thank you very much!

Edit: Made the outer margin a bit larger and added two examples.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{scrartcl}        

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=29mm, inner=30mm, outer=25mm, bottom=30mm,
headsep=8.9mm, footskip=13.8mm}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
                        style=numeric-comp, 
                        sorting=none,
                        maxnames=3,
                        minnames=3,
                        language=ngerman,
                        hyperref=true,
                        date=iso8601,
                        arxiv=ps,
                        texencoding=utf8,
                        bibencoding=utf8,
                        firstinits=true,
                        terseinits=false,
                        useprefix=true,
                        ]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis,book,inproceedings,patent]{title}{\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{PatentLeistungsschutzschalter, FGLBeispielAntenne, FGLBeispielChirugie}       

\printbibliography

\end{document}



@Patent{PatentLeistungsschutzschalter,
  Title                    = {Leitungsschutzschalter},
  Author                   = {{BBC Brown Boveri Cie, Niemeyer, L.}},
  Date                     = {1979-11-05},
  Number                   = {DE2944579A1},
  Type                     = {Patentschrift},
}

@Online{FGLBeispielChirugie,
  Title                    = {Nitinol Führungsdrähte für PiCCO-Katheter},
  Author                   = {{Pulsion Medical Systems}},
  Date                     = {2013-07-05},
  Url                      = {http://www3.pulsion.de/fileadmin/pulsion_share/Products_Flyer/Nitinol_Anwenderinfo_D_MPI700400_R02_030708.pdf},
}

@Online{FGLBeispielAntenne,
  Title                    = {Leitfaden für HF-Entwickler - Antennenmaterial},
  Author                   = {{Circuit Design GmbH}},
  Date                     = {2013-07-05},
  Url                      = {http://www.circuitdesign.de/products/tech_info/guide3.asp},
}
```

Comment: not relevant to the question, but i believe that "Brown Boveri" is misspelled.  regarding not breaking a date at hyphens, i'd be inclined (depending on the rest of the bibliography) to set it ragged right, and suppress all hyphens, including explicit ones (using `\exhyphenpenalty=10000`).

Comment: Can you come up with an MWE where the date is actually broken, because it seems LaTeX is very very reluctant to do so (I could not make it do so). Or do I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Edited my MWE for better understanding

Comment: You could, as barbarabeeton suggests use `block=ragged`.

Comment: Why is `block=ragged` not acceptable if you want line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add extra formatting to a field in the `.bib` file by either adding

- `\allowbreak`, to allow a line break, or
- `\hyphenate` (from the `biblatex` package), to add an optional hyphen:

[image: Sample output]

Literatur.bib

```
@Patent{PatentLeistungsschutzschalter,
  Title                    = {Leitungsschutzschalter},
  Author                   = {{BBC Brown Boveri Cie, Niemeyer, L.}},
  Date                     = {1979-11-05},
  Number                   = {DE\allowbreak 2944\allowbreak 579A1},
  Type                     = {Patentschrift},
}

@Patent{PatentLeistungsschutzschalter2,
  Title                    = {Leitungsschutzschalter},
  Author                   = {{BBC Brown Boveri Cie, Niemeyer, L.}},
  Date                     = {1979-11-05},
  Number                   = {DE\hyphenate 2944\hyphenate 579A1},
  Type                     = {Patentschrift},
}

@Online{FGLBeispielChirugie,
  Title                    = {Nitinol Führungsdrähte für PiCCO-Katheter},
  Author                   = {{Pulsion Medical Systems}},
  Date                     = {2013-07-05},
  Url                      = {http://www3.pulsion.de/fileadmin/pulsion_share/Products_Flyer/Nitinol_Anwenderinfo_D_MPI700400_R02_030708.pdf},
}

@Online{FGLBeispielAntenne,
  Title                    = {Leitfaden für HF-Entwickler - Antennenmaterial},
  Author                   = {{Circuit Design GmbH}},
  Date                     = {2013-07-05},
  Url                      = {http://www.circuitdesign.de/products/tech_info/guide3.asp},
}
```

LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{scrartcl}        

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=29mm, inner=30mm, outer=25mm, bottom=30mm,
headsep=8.9mm, footskip=13.8mm}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
                        style=numeric-comp, 
                        sorting=none,
                        maxnames=3,
                        minnames=3,
                        language=ngerman,
                        hyperref=true,
                        date=iso8601,
                        arxiv=ps,
                        texencoding=utf8,
                        bibencoding=utf8,
                        firstinits=true,
                        terseinits=false,
                        useprefix=true,
                        ]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis,book,inproceedings,patent]{title}{\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{PatentLeistungsschutzschalter,PatentLeistungsschutzschalter2, FGLBeispielAntenne, FGLBeispielChirugie}       

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```